# Ошибка Android ndk, как исправить?

Tags: ndk

c:\ndk>ndk-build -C c:/jni
make: Entering directory `c:/jni' [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "samp <= CCheckFileHash.cpp" process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, c:/ndk/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF c:/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/samp/CCheckFileHash.o.d -gcc-toolchain c:/ndk/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-integrated-as -g -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi14 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -DNDEBUG -Ic:/jni/vendor/ -Ic:/ndk/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -Ic:/ndk/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -Ic:/ndk/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -Ic:/jni -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=14 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -w -s -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -Wall -fpack-struct=1 -O2 -std=c++14 -fexceptions --sysroot c:/ndk/build//../sysroot -isystem c:/ndk/build//../sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -c c:/jni/CCheckFileHash.cpp -o c:/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/samp/CCheckFileHash.o, ...) failed. make (e=2): Не удается найти указанный файл. make: *** [c:/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/samp/CCheckFileHash.o] Error 2 make: Leaving directory` c:/jni'

Как исправить?

Comment: А где ваш код? Без него мы вряд ли сможем вам чем нибудь помочь.